# Cannot access remote network using forticlient ssl VPN

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, ssl

I'm using forticlient to connect to VPN, the forticlient connection works fine but can't ping or access any remote host.

This is the forticlient CLI output:

```
STATUS::Login succeed
STATUS::Starting PPPd
STATUS::Initializing tunnel
STATUS::Connecting to server
STATUS::Connected
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

And this is the route table:

```
[/etc/openvpn]>route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         airbox.orange   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx98ded005499d
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlx98ded005499d
190.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx98ded005499d
192.168.105.0   172.30.1.2      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ppp0
194.50.35.48    airbox.orange   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlx98ded005499d
```

But can't ping anything there:

```
[/etc/openvpn]>ping 192.168.105.0
PING 192.168.105.0 (192.168.105.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
......
......
forever
```

And by tracking the route:

```
[/etc/openvpn]>ip route get  192.168.1.0
192.168.1.0 dev ppp0  src 172.30.1.2 
    cache
```

The same result using forticleint GUI.
Using Windows it works completely fine.
Please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: it's been 3 months, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I tried a lot with no hope, I migrated all my work to Windows since it works fine there. but still wait an answer since it's better to work in Linux.

Comment: very extreme solution, I've had success with using the Android app and then tethering my laptop to that